# How to extract the MAX number from the query

Tags: soql, query, aggregateresult

The following `SOQL` gives me the list of max rows with quantity/product name
but I'm only looking to extract the maximum quantity out of all the records.

Do I need to loop to get that?

```
   SELECT max(Quantity__c) qty,  product_name__c FROM Asset_line_item__c 
     where Id = 'xxxxx'
    group by product_name__c
```

I have tried with `AggregateResult`.

```
AggregateResult[] result =  [max(Quantity__c) qty,  
              product_name__c FROM Asset_line_item__c where Id = 'xxxxx' 
              group by product_name__c];
```

Comment: Are you just looking for the numerically highest Quantity value of all Asset Line Items? Why are you filtering on `Id`, since that will only look at one record?

Comment: Isn't it as simple as dropping the `GROUP BY` clause?

Comment: @JeremyNottingham: thats correct i'm looking for the highest qty value.

Comment: @DerekF: you will get an error if you drop group by `MALFORMED_QUERY: Field must be grouped or aggregated`

Comment: Can you order by Quantity__c and limit 1

Comment: You can't use `LIMIT` clauses in aggregate queries...

Comment: Drop the `WHERE` filters, `order by Quantity__c DESC` and `limit 1`. Normal SOQL.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to just use `get('qty')` or even `get('expr0')`.

```
for (AggregateResult aggregate : [
    SELECT MAX(Quantity__c) qty,  Product_Name__c FROM Asset_Line_Item__c 
    WHERE ... GROUP BY Product_Name__c
]) system.debug(aggregate.get('Product_Name__c') + ' - ' + aggregate.get('qty');
```

Or if you just want the highest max and felt compelled to use aggregation:

```
Decimal max;
for (AggregateResult aggregate : [
    SELECT MAX(Quantity__c) qty,  Product_Name__c FROM Asset_Line_Item__c 
    WHERE ...
    GROUP BY Product_Name__c
    ORDER BY MAX(Quantity__c) DESC
]){
    max = (Decimal)aggregate.get('qty');
    break;
}
```

Or, as noted in the comments, just get the single highest value with no aggregation at all.

```
Decimal max = [
    SELECT Quantity__c FROM Asset_Line_Item__c
    ORDER BY Quantity__c DESC LIMIT 1
].Quantity;
```

Comment: tried the last one which is `decimal max....` got this error: ERROR:
MALFORMED_QUERY: unexpected token: Decimal

Comment: Sounds like it got pasted in at the wrong spot. It should be a line all on its own.

Answer (score 1):

try this.

```
[SELECT Quantity__c, product_name__c FROM Asset_line_item__c order by          
                                          Quantity__c DESC limit 1];
```

Comment: Whoever negged this post care to explain why?

Comment: I like it very simple and i do not have to deal with AggregateResult, why i did not think of that :(

Comment: @Nick That's almost exactly the same query you said you couldn't get to work from the end of my post. I guess you got it working after all?

Comment: two things I see different then what i was doing 1) DESC and 2) LIMIT 1